# Setting the sortorder using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am working on Spring-MVC. I am using hibernate as the ORM tool. There is table which has a column called 'NoteOrder'. SO for any CRUD operations, the order of data in database is managed by NoteOrder.

Question : After any CRUD operation, I would like to reset the noteorder starting with 1 and incrementing until end of that table.

How can I achieve this using Hibernate queries. I searched for something similar, couldnt find any. I am posting the code below for reference. The function returns a list.

```
@Override
    public List<Notes> listNotesBySectionId(int sectionid, Person person) {
        int personid = person.getId();
        if(session == null) {
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        }else {
            session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Notes as n where n.person1.id=:id and n.sectionid=:sectionid  order by n.noteorder");
        query.setParameter("id",personid);
        query.setParameter("sectionid",sectionid);
        List<Notes> notesList = query.list();  // this list has the noteorder by asking notelist.getNoteOrder();
        System.out.println("Notes per sectionid per person are" + notesList);
        return notesList;

    }
```

Comment: You want to maintain order of the Notes by column NoteOrder? After every CRUD (without read, I guess) operation you want to reset/update NoteOrder?

Comment: Not after read...sorry...only after create, update, delete. Rest what you asked is correct.

Comment: When you add some Note it will go to the end (with highest NoteOrder)? And when you remove Note then every Note with higher index should be updated (decremented by 1)?

Comment: Exactly....or if updated...then too...any idea how to achieve this feat?

Comment: Can you post your Notes and Person entities.

Comment: I am not in office right now. But why is person entity or notes entity requires for this..it just has variables, getters and setters.

Comment: Because you can achieve your request by updating them, If I guessing right your Person has @OneToMany relationship to Notes?

Comment: Yes..its onetomany mapping using column names. Can you type in some pseudo code as answer...i will comment on that tomorrow and update post with entities. You will be automatically notified.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `@OrderColumn` annotation, for example entry;

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderColumn(name="noteorder")
    private List<Notes> notes;

...
```

From documentation about OrderColumn

> Specifies a column that is used to maintain the persistent order of a
>   list. The persistence provider is responsible for maintaining the
>   order upon retrieval and in the database. The persistence provider is
>   responsible for updating the ordering upon flushing to the database to
>   reflect any insertion, deletion, or reordering affecting the list.

In this case `@OrderColumn` will create column with name `noteorder` in your Notes table, and it will have same indices as they are in notes list, so every reordering will affect `noteorder`. Your query should work now.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This will sort the entire database of notes. As you can see from my NotesDaoImpl...i am only retreiving list per person with given sectionid. The output is in format of list. Is it possible to sort that list? I can retrieve noteorder by noteslist.getNoteorder().

Comment: This will sort Notes by Person. So every Person object will have its own order.